# Previously selected option for ui-select change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below `ui-select` html:

```
<ui-select ng-model="actionSelectedId" 
    on-select="changedAction($item, $select, row)"
    theme="bootstrap"
    ng-disabled="disabled">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select an action">    
        <span>{{$select.selected.name || $select.search}}</span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="action.id as action in actions | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="action.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I want to retrieve previously selected action id in `changedAction` method in the controller

e.g. method call from html would be like below will give previously selected value, so need to know how can I get `oldSelection`:

`on-select="changedAction($item, $select, row, oldSelection)"`

Please let me know if this is possible with [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.$watch('actionSelectedId', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.oldValue = oldValue;
    $scope.newValue = newValue;
});
```

Comment: thanks, this works for simple `ui-select`. Actually I have complex `ui-select`. It will be in each table row so `actionSelectedId` is actually `row.actionSelectedId` that is why I can not put watch on it.